# Angular - Change detection inside Service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-changedetection

I'm working on an Angular application. I need to listen to changes in a dataset (javascript object) inside one of my **services**.

I'm familiar with Angular's `KeyValueDiffers` (listener on Objects) and with `IterableDiffers` (listener on Arrays). And if I want to listen to changes inside Angular-Components then:

1. I will implement the `DoCheck` interface in my component, by implementing a `NgDoCheck` method.
2. I will initialize the `KeyValueDiffers` and/or the `IterableDiffers` and inside the `NgDoCheck` method, I will check for changes.

However, this technique will not work inside an Angular Service since service don't implement the DoCheck interface (The DoCheck isn't part of the Services LifeCycle).

So my question how can I listen to Object/Array change inside Angular service?

Comment: You can't. Proceed from this fact and develop them accordingly. It's component's responsibility to notify service of changes - via observables or method calls. A service can get hold of component's ChangeDetectorRef, but only if it's component's provider, and depending on the case this may be considered antipattern. Consider explaining your case further and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you're interested in alternative solution.

Comment: @estus excellent comment, you should make it an answer

Comment: @Phil I'm trying to stick to constructive answers when possible. I guess the answer should include this information and provide a possible way to solve the problem. A feedback from OP would be valuable at this point.

Comment: @estus, thank you for your comment. Indeed I solve this by implementing the pattern I write in the question, inside a component, and when the component noticed a change, the component invoked a method in the service. But I was asking can I avoid involving the component in this flow.

Comment: This would prevent the separation of business from presentation logic; basically an antipattern. This is what components are for. Whether it's possible or not depends on your code. If it's local provider, then it is. If it is a provider from parent injector, then it isn't.